# javascript force ngx-slider trigger drag

Tags: javascript, dom

https://angular-slider.github.io/ngx-slider/

How it be possible start drag-slide event with Pure JS

for example

```
var dom = document.querySelector('span.ngx-slider-span.ngx-slider-pointer.ngx-slider-pointer-min');

dom.setAttribute('aria-valueno',65)
dom.setAttribute('aria-valuetext',65)
dom.change()
```

making manuplation from outside

Comment: How is this related to PureScript?

Comment: Controlling from outside forexample console

Comment: PureScript is a programming language. I think this was tagged inappropriately so have removed it.

Comment: Yeah, I had knew it but i put about means however, thanks for your suggestion i changed

Answer (score 1):

Use ngx-slider values I assuming you are using this in angular project the value property is the left pointer(start) and highValue(end).
Then go to the ts file when applying `this.startPoint++` the start point will move one tick. just remember to update slider to view the changes.

`<ngx-slider [(value)]="startPoint" [(highValue)]="endPoint" [options]="options"></ngx-slider>`

for more please read documentation in [ngx-slider](https://github.com/angular-slider/ngx-slider)